# Pylons: how can I supply a GET parameter in a URL controller call?

Tags: pylons

I've got a functional test running in Pylons. It calls a page as follows:

```
    response = self.app.get(url(controller='search', action='index'))
    assert not 'hello' in response
```

This is looking at `/search`, but I'd like to know how to look for `/search?q=hello`. The controller looks for a GET parameter called `q` in the url, as follows:

```
class SearchController(BaseController):
    def index(self):
        c.q = request.params.get('q', None)
```

How can I supply a `q` parameter in the self.app.get call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

response = self.app.get(url(controller='search',action='index'),
                                params={'q':'My query'})